# express.js object values remain/persist between requests, require() cache?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm fairly new to node/express but love it so far.

One thing I've noticed after writing a few apps now, is that property values of the request object will sometimes persist between requests within required modules; and not necessarily from the same IP or even browser.

Take for example, this super simple GET request:

```
GET /lookup/?first=ben&last=ipsen
```

Which gets handled something like this:

```
app.get('/lookup/', function(req, res){ 
     lookup = require('lookup')
     lookup.find_user(req, res, function(err, user){
        if(err) throw new Error(err) 
        res.send(user) 
     });

 });
```

Obviously, this works well and life is great. However...
If a second request is received with empty or absent values, say:

```
 GET /lookup/?first=

app.get('/lookup/', function(req, res){ 
     lookup = require('lookup')
     lookup.find_user(req, res, function(err, user){
        if(err) throw new Error(err) 
        // user.first = ben 
        // user.last = ipsen !?
        res.send(user) 
     });

 });
```

Is this an issue caused by the require cache and not express' fault?  Am I making a mistake by loading a modules within a request? There are many cases where I want to load a specific module based on the request but I can live without that 'require'ment.. har.

I'm surely experiencing some novice issues here, but as always any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Side note, `require` is synchronous. Do it at the top of your module before your web app starts listening for network requests to avoid blocking your server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with the `require()` cache.  It's only going to return the same object every time, and there is nothing wrong with this.

I suspect the problem is your `lookup` module.  You've probably defined a variable globally or forgot to use `var` in front of it.

Comment: Yeah, I've been advised via Twitter that loading modules at runtime isn't a good idea on each request. Even still, you're right about the module likely being the problem, I've taken require() out of the equation at this point but all looks well with the module. Unfortunately it's contract work so I cant post it but maybe sudo code it in another question. Thanks!